# Question on equivalence classes in a relation

Tags: abstract-algebra, relations, equivalence-relations

Let $S$ = $\{(x,y)^T : x,y \in \Bbb{R}\}$.

Define a relation $R$ on $S$ by $aRb$ iff there exists a $2\times2$ invertible matrix $A$ such that $Aa$ = $b$.

I have shown that $R$ is an equivalence relation.

I need to show that $R$ partitions $S$ into $4$ distinct classes.

Let $ a \in S$ and $[a]$ denote the equivalence class of $a$.

Then by definition,

$[a]$ = $\{b \in S:  \exists\;\; 2\times2  \text{ invertible matrix } A \text{ s.t }  Aa = b\}$

I  can't understand how can I proceed after this.

Comment: Unless one of them is zero, wouldn't you always have such matrix?

Comment: Perhaps you are trying to prove that $\forall a, b,\; aRb$ iff $\exists$ a $2\times 2$ invertible matrix $A$ such that $A a= b$.  In that case, we need to prove that for each pair (a, b), there is some matrix A satisfying the above.

Comment: But I need to find the number of equivalence classes.@BinyaminR.

Comment: are you saying there will be 1 equivalence class?..@amWhy

Comment: yes.. i think (0,0) will form its own equivalence class.